# Wrong values for parameters send using MultipartFormData

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipart

All I do is simply like:

```swift
    func postMultipart(_ url: URL, parameters: [String: Any]?, headers: [String: String]?, image: UIImage?, success: @escaping SuccessHandler, failure: @escaping ErrorHandler) {
        manager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipart in
            if let image = image, let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                multipart.append(data, withName: "Passport", fileName: "picture.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }
            if let parameters = parameters {
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipart.append(self.archiver.data(from: value), withName: key)
                }
            }
        }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { result in
            //parse result here
        }
    }
```

And this is what I see as a result of my multipart send to serwer:

[image]

You may see that it is wrong. It should look like this:

```
PMSReservationID: "23".
```

Why it is not a string, but some archiver object?

Answer (score 0):

You may need it like

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
   multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
}
```

Comment: my value is different depend on context. It may be: `String`, `Number` or even an another dictionary. Will it work also then?